# how to get a LinkedHashMap from the list using stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to grouped the list by position and sorted by age and into a `LinkedHashMap`.

If I put it into a `HashMap`, the result will not be sorted. I can't figure out how to create `LinkedHashMap<String, Map<Integer, List<Worker>>>`.
I wanted to get the result so that the linkedhashmap would be grouped by profession and sorted by age

```java
class Worker {

    String name;
    int age;
    int salary;
    String position;

    public Worker(String name, int age, int salary, String position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Worker("Ann", 50, 15000, "doctor"),
                new Worker("Kate", 15, 1500, "doctor"),
                new Worker("Mike", 23, 12333, "nurse"),
                new Worker("Mike", 63, 12333, "nurse")));

        Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Worker>>> collect = workers.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Worker::position,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Worker::age)));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite unclear. What is the expected output? Do you really want to create a LinkedHashMap or just to sort that list by multiple criteria? Currently you are not sorting anything just group by position and age.

Comment: You could use `workers.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Worker::position).thenComparingInt(Worker::age)).toList()`.

Comment: I'm confused myself. I thought that grouping by age would be sorting. I wanted to get the result so that the linkedhashmap would be grouped by profession and sorted by age

Comment: If you just want to replace the default `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap`, you can use the 3-arg version of `Collectors::groupingBy`: `workers.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(worker::position, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.groupingBy(worker::age, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())))`. But it will not give you a map where keys are sorted.

Comment: @MC Emperor i need result put in linkedHashMap<String, Map<Integer, List<Worker>>>

Comment: @KtoTam based on your comment please update the question with the desired output

Comment: Grouping is not the same as sorting. Grouping is putting all items in specific buckets based on some property of each item. This has little to do with sorting, which is the *order* in which the items are observed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly from the comments, you need the list to be

- grouped by profession,
- sorted by age
- collected into a LinkedHashMap

If this is the case, you can try something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Worker>> groupedByProfession = workers.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Worker::getAge))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Worker::getPosition, 
            LinkedHashMap::new, 
            Collectors.toList()
         ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Worker>>> collect = workers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Worker::getPosition, 
                Collectors.groupingBy(Worker::getAge, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList())));
```